# jQuery flip opacity change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/bfQMD/11/

Im using flip pluging and how to change opacity.

Comment: Open up the flip code and modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, as mentioned by Diodeus, is to modify the flip plugin – which is kinda hacky, obviously.

See [the working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bfQMD/16/)

The changes I made were basically

`opacity : 0`,

`opacity : 0.5` and

`opacity : 1`

in

`defaultStart`,

`defaultVertical.first`/`defaultVertical.second` and

`defaultHorizontal.first`/`defaultHorizontal.second`

respectively.

Since the plugin uses `jQuery.animate()` internally, this was all it took.